# How to display items on cart page from shopping page

Tags: jquery, html

I want when I click add to cart on shopping page, it displays on cart page with it's details and cannot remove there even if I refresh unless i click remove.
The products are coming from a json file

```html
<!-- shopping HTML -->
<div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="items">
                    <div class='photo'>
                        <img src="${item.imagelink}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <h5>${item.name}</h5>
                        <h5>$${item.price}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="add">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary add">Add to cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```html
<!--Cart HTML  -->
<div class="product-image">
                <img src="${item.imagelink}">
            </div>
            <div class="product-name">
                <div class="product-title">${item.name}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-price">$${item.price}</div>
            <div class="product-quantity">
                <input type="number" value="1" min="1">
            </div>
            <div class="product-line-price">45.99</div>
```

```js
//when add to cart is clicked
$('button.add').click(function () {
        let output = '';
        output += `

            <div class="product-image">
                <img src="${item.imagelink}">
            </div>
            <div class="product-name">
                <div class="product-title">${item.name}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-price">$${item.price}</div>
            <div class="product-quantity">
                <input type="number" value="1" min="1">
            </div>
            <div class="product-line-price">45.99</div>
        `;
        $('.product').html(output);
    });
```

Comment: Do you know how cookies work?

Comment: No please help out

Answer (score 0):

You should use cookies. Cookies are basically information that is stored in files on the computer. A web site (like an online shop) can read out the information and display it on a web page accordingly. I will explain in short how to use them with JavaScript. For further information, there is a nice tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Set a cookie like this:

```
document.cookie = "item1name=Gamepad"
```

Read the value of a cookie like this:

```
var x = document.cookie
```

So a minimal example with your code would be

```
<!-- shopping HTML -->
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="items">
    <div class='photo'>
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h5 class='item-name'>Gamepad</h5>
      <h5 class='item-price'>$ 49.99</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="add">
      <button class="btn btn-primary add">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('button.add').click(function () {
    var itemName = $('.item-name').text();
    var itemPrice = $('.item-price').text();
    document.cookie = 'itemName=' + itemName;
    document.cookie = 'itemPrice=' + itemPrice;
  });
</script>
```